# How can i create this custom Staggered Grid in flutter?

Tags: flutter

There is some way to create a list of images taken from a website and show them as this grid. for example i have 20 images from XYZ website and i want to show all of them following the grid estructure

[image]

and i use this code to make the custom grid:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body:Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white
      ),
      child: StaggeredGridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        mainAxisSpacing: 4,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4,
        staggeredTiles: [
          StaggeredTile.count(3, 2),
          StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
          StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
          StaggeredTile.count(1, 2),
          StaggeredTile.count(3, 2),
          StaggeredTile.count(3, 2),
          StaggeredTile.count(1, 2),
        ],
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(color: Colors.deepPurple,),
          Container(color: Colors.red,),
          Container(color: Colors.orangeAccent,),
          Container(color: Colors.blueAccent,),
          Container(color: Colors.yellow,),
          Container(color: Colors.grey,),
          Container(color: Colors.greenAccent,),
        ],
      )
    )
  )
);
```

I tried by making a list of the images URL and using the following code but i dont know how to respect the grid that was show before.

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        mainAxisSpacing: 20,
        crossAxisSpacing: 20,
        itemCount: imageList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(placeholder: kTransparentImage,image: imageList[index], fit: BoxFit.cover,),
        ),
      );
    }, staggeredTileBuilder: (index){
      return StaggeredTile.count(1, index.isEven? 1.2 : 1.8);
    }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i update the estructure to 10 conteiners instead of 7 and create a function that returns me the StaggeredTitle that i need by using MOD 10 here is the code:

```
StaggeredTile configuracion(int index) {
index = index + 1;
switch (index % 10) {
  case 1:
    {
      return StaggeredTile.count(3, 2);
    }
  case 2:
    {
      return StaggeredTile.count(1, 1);
    }
  case 3:
    {
      return StaggeredTile.count(1, 1);
    }
  case 4:
    {
      return StaggeredTile.count(1, 2);
    }
  case 5:
    {
      return StaggeredTile.count(3, 2);
    }
  case 6:
    {
      return StaggeredTile.count(3, 2);
    }
  case 7:
    {
      return StaggeredTile.count(1, 2);
    }
  case 8:
    {
      return StaggeredTile.count(1, 1);
    }
  case 9:
    {
      return StaggeredTile.count(3, 2);
    }
  case 10:
    {
      return StaggeredTile.count(1, 1);
    }
  default:
    {
      return StaggeredTile.count(1, 1);
    }
}
```

}